# EFI missing, Question folder appears, Mac SSD appears and disappears, what do I do?

Tags: hard-drive, partition, ssd, efi, guid

Setup Macbook Pro retina 13 A1502, SSD 128Gb
Running Yosemite, but currently doing the update for high sierra.

Problem: Question marked folder appear after I left it for 2 days, battery run out (left it on sleep I think with minimal battery). 
It showed me a black screen I turned off&on again and folder with question marked appeared. 
I tried to reinstall using recovery tools, doesn't even show a selectable disk. Tried to Verify and Repair, nothing.

I created a bootable external OS X, from which I'm asking this, and I partitioned the SSD into 1. 
Curious thing: OS X was in a different partition from the ssd. 
Another curious thing is that the sdd disappears after I try something. 
At some point I think it was in the hardware diagnose I found a error that pointed that EFI was broken. 
I ran `sudo gpt -r show disk0s2` 
and this showed

```
  start       size  index  contents
      0  236568496
```

EDIT: 
The disks images I have
(the Apple SSD long name)
   disk0s2

(External disk long name)
   disk1 (renamed by me trying to follow a solution)

Disk2
   OS X Base System

The result of the disk verifying tool

```
"The Partition Map needs to be repaired because there is a problem with the EFI system partition's file system"
```

The Hardware diagnostic result

```
Reference code vdh002
```

Running gdisk
`sudo gdisk /dev/disk0s2`

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.4

Partition table scan:
  MBR: not present
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
```

I tried the answers provided to similar questions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1122951/primary-gpt-is-missing-and-filevault-volume-too), [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7056781?tstart=0), and [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/221114/how-to-fix-broken-gpt-guid-and-unmountable-no-type-volumes).  None of them resolved my problem.

I guess I need to rebuild the EFI? What do I need to do?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  There's dozens of answers already provided for similar problems.  Have you reviewed any of the answers already provided?  If so, which ones did you try and didn't work for you?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/221114/how-to-fix-broken-gpt-guid-and-unmountable-no-type-volumes
https://superuser.com/questions/1122951/primary-gpt-is-missing-and-filevault-volume-too
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7056781?tstart=0

Comment: I added those to your question.  Comments can be deleted so important info should be added to the question.  If I got any of the wording wrong, please feel free to correct it.