# Mac M1 Sonoma: Cannot read my 256Gb Micro SD card

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition, sd-card

I have a brand new 256Gb SanDisk Micro SD card and I'm not being able to read/use in my Mac through the internal SD Card reader slot (I don't have an external card reader to try this option).

The card was working at the very beginning, but after a format (or something I don't remember) it become not recognized by SO.

I've tried "Disk Utility" format (Erase) with all partition types (ExtFAT, Mac OS Extended, etc) to no avail. It formats the card successfully, but then it is still unseen by "Finder".

I've also tried "First Aid" in "Disk Utility" to no avail too, it does the recovery with no errors, but the card continue to be unseen, so I cannot write to it.

I've been reading [How to fix broken GPT, GUID and unmountable, no type volumes?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/221114/how-to-fix-broken-gpt-guid-and-unmountable-no-type-volumes), but I'm currently stuck.

If I do (in Terminal):

```
sudo gpt -v show /dev/disk4
```

The response is:

```
gpt show: /dev/disk4: mediasize=255869321216; sectorsize=512; blocks=499744768
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         MBR
          1      65535         
      65536  499679232      1  MBR part 7
```

Any help in order to make my SD Card to be recognized/work? I'd prefer to use ExtFAT so it can then be read in Windows as well as in my Android mobile.

Edit 1: After @David Anderson suggestion.

```
diskutil erasedisk exfat MyExFAT mbr disk4
Started erase on disk4
Unmounting disk
Creating the partition map
Waiting for partitions to activate
Formatting disk4s1 as ExFAT with name MyExFAT
Reformatting existing ExFAT volume
Volume name      : MyExFAT
Partition offset : 65536 sectors (33554432 bytes)
Volume size      : 499679232 sectors (255835766784 bytes)
Bytes per sector : 512
Bytes per cluster: 262144
FAT offset       : 32768 sectors (16777216 bytes)
# FAT sectors    : 7680
Number of FATs   : 1
Cluster offset   : 65536 sectors (33554432 bytes)
# Clusters       : 975808
Volume Serial #  : 6ab00ea2
Bitmap start     : 2
Bitmap file size : 121976
Upcase start     : 3
Upcase file size : 5836
Root start       : 4
Mounting disk
Could not mount disk4s1 after erase
Finished erase on disk4
```

Comment: Theres a very comprehensive QA on this at SuperUser - http://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only which is well worth the read.

Comment: Can you format it on your Windows machine and see what happens? (Assuming you have, or have access to, a Windows machine.)

Comment: Have you got a camera you can try it in, and see if the camera will format it?

Comment: @Andy Griffiths the idea of the camera was good, didn't realize and I have a Nikon reflex. I'm trying, but now its been almost 5 minutes and the camera is still on "Formatting the card". Maybe this is because it's a 256Gb card, or maybe the camera software just got stuck, don't know. I'll wait some more time before turning the camera off, I wouldn't like to damage the card.

Comment: @IconDaemon thanks for your input, I have a Windows laptop too, but inserting the card into the internal sdcard slot it is not recognized. After the camera ends (or I decide to force quit) I'll try in Windows again.

Comment: @Tetsujin thank you very much for your help, I'll have a look at the link :)

Comment: @Andy Griffiths, maybe the problem is my Nikon D7000 max sd card supported size is 128Gb, and it got stuck because of that... The weird thing is that the green light -which indicates writing is in progress- is still blinking.

Comment: No matter what I try... I've tried Windows Paragon Partition Manager also, and with different filesystems, but the sd card cannot be mounted, even when it is seen :( No more help?

Comment: I think you may not be using the Disk Utility to erase the entire drive. You could try `diskutil erasedisk exfat MyExFAT mbr disk4`. Here, I assume the drive identifier is still `disk4`.

Comment: Please, see my edit @David Anderson.